# Twig include variable path name with concatenation

Tags: php, twig

How do I specify an `include` to a view path that is a "concatenation". A simple example;

In form.twig;

```
{% include {path: 'survey.'group]} %}
```

`group` is a variable, that is passed in to the view from the controller. The view I am trying to load here is views/survey/example.twig

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [twig concatenation operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) is ~.

So you should have have something like

```
 {% include 'survey/' ~ group ~ '.html.twig' %}
```

(or however exactly your concatenation needs to go).